# match and file line between two patterns

Tags: perl, multiline

I am trying to create a perl script which will capture a line(s) in between two Patterns and store it to new file.

This is how lines in file Looks like.

```
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 fmd: [ID 377184 daemon.error] SUNW-MSG-ID: FMD-8000-CV,
TYPE: Alert, VER: 1, SEVERITY: Minor
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 EVENT-TIME: Fri Apr 17 15:56:28 EDT 2015
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 PLATFORM: SUN SERVER X4-4, CSN: 1421NM900G, HOSTNAME: bur-7430
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 SOURCE: software-diagnosis, REV: 0.1
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 EVENT-ID: b22c3c73-77d7-4f4e-8030-c589bf057bb9
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 DESC: FRU '/SYS/HDD0' has been removed from the system.
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 AUTO-RESPONSE: FMD topology will be updated.
```

i am trying with following codes with no luck.

```
use warnings;
my $filename = /tmp/fname.txt;
my $fextract;
{
   open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "can not open file -filename.\n$!\n";
   local $/ = undef;
   $fextract = <$fh>;
}

while(
      $fextract =~ m/SUNW-MSG-ID(.*)DESC/gs
     )
{
print "$1\n";
}
```

script runs perfectly fine but it result nothing.

can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me with your code (with quote on the file)

```
> perl script.pl 
: FMD-8000-CV,
TYPE: Alert, VER: 1, SEVERITY: Minor
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 EVENT-TIME: Fri Apr 17 15:56:28 EDT 2015
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 PLATFORM: SUN SERVER X4-4, CSN: 1421NM900G, HOSTNAME: bur-7430
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 SOURCE: software-diagnosis, REV: 0.1
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430 EVENT-ID: b22c3c73-77d7-4f4e-8030-c589bf057bb9
Apr 17 15:57:35 bur-7430
```